# Order reduction: where am I making a mistake?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $y''-\frac{2x+3}{x+1}y'+\frac{x+2}{x+1}y=0$, you may use that $y_1(x)=e^x$ is a solution

So I thought of order reduction, assuming that $y_2(x)=v(x)\cdot e^x$

Set $v'(x)=u(x)$, using the theorem, we know that ($P(x)=\frac{2x+3}{x+1}$):
$$u=\frac{e^{- \int P(x) dx}}{y_1(x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{e^{\int \frac{2x+3}{x+1}dx}}{e^{2x}}=...=e^2(x+1)$$

Considering $v'(x)=u(x)$, we obtain
$$v(x)=\int e^2(x+1)dx=e^2(\frac{x^2}{2}+x)$$

And hence $$y_2(x)=e^{2+x}(\frac{x^2}{2}+x)$$ should be a solution. 
However, using this does not work. Could anyone point out where I made the mistake?

Comment: There must be a typo since $e^x$ is not solution but $e^{-x}$ is

Comment: Thanks for answering, I made a sign mistake in the excersise. Changed it now. $P(x)$ should have been $-(2x+3)/(x+1)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int -\frac{2x+3}{x+1}dx = -\int 2+\frac{1}{x+1}dx = -2x + \ln(\frac{1}{x+1}) $$

So $$u(x)=\frac{e^{2x+\ln(\frac{1}{x+1})}}{e^{2x}}=\frac{e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}(x+1)}=\frac{e^{-4x}}{x+1}$$